# InvalidApiVersionParameter-When I am trying to create VM on Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

When I am trying to create VM on Azure by Azure Java SDK, I got the error message shown below.

[InvalidApiVersionParameter: The api-version '2015-06-15' is invalid. The supported versions are '2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z6Gk.png)

It seems my api-version is incorrect. However, I didn't set this api-version in the code. How to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: its the last version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the latest version of Azure Java SDK by using Maven.

There are [the Maven Repositories of Azure Java SDKs](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure).

According to your needs, you can add the maven dependencies below in the `pom.xml` file of your project if you want to create Azure VMs.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt-compute</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```